# QGIS quickest method of calculating distance between multiple points in one layer?

Tags: qgis, point, distance

Using Qgis 2.18.3, I am looking for the quickest method of calculating the aggregated distance between multiple points. As the Crow flies would be enough...

I have a  point layer in a small area. They have unique and incremented ID's. 
(in my case these are stops of a truck)

I was using the Points to path plugin to create lines. Then using $length to calculate the length and then basic statistic to aggregate the length. 
I could build a model to automate this a little.
The thing is that I have hundreds of those seperate point layers...

Is there an other method which is quicker?

Answer (score 4):

You could also make a shell script for all your files so you don't have to sit around waiting for QGIS to be ready. In this example the points are shape files and [saga_cmd](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/shapes_lines_1.html) and [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) is used.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.shp

do
    f=$(echo $i| cut -d'.' -f 1) 
    saga_cmd shapes_lines 1 -LINES ${f}_line.shp -POINTS ${f}
    ogrinfo ${f}_line.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE ${f}_line ADD COLUMN length integer(5)"
    ogrinfo ${f}_line.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE ${f}_line SET length = ST_Length(geometry)"
done
```

Then you'll get polyline shape file for each point file with a new column showing length of the line. You could also add options to `saga_cmd` with order of points etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a **custom script** (or a model but I prefer script) which runs the `Field Calculator` and the `Convert points to lines` to create an output of a single line joining all points with a *Length* field containing the aggregated length.

You can create one from:

```
Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
```

Then use something like the following:

```
##Example=name
##Point_layer=vector point
##ID_Field=Field Point_layer
##Result=output vector

output_fieldCalculator = processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", Point_layer, 'Separate', 1, 10, 0, True, '1', None)
output_pointToLine = processing.runalg("saga:convertpointstolines", output_fieldCalculator['OUTPUT_LAYER'], ID_Field, "Separate", None)
output_fieldLength = processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", output_pointToLine['LINES'], 'Length', 0, 10, 2, True, '$length', Result)
```

Make sure to save the script into your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts` directory.

---

Example:

When you run the script, you can select the point layer and the ID field:

[image: Script]

Result:

[image: Example]

---

*Note: The "Separate" field is only used for the SAGA tool to create the line correctly.*